# Can you place non-string tag value to a combobox in xaml declaration?

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I was wondering if there is a way to set the tag value of a combobox to a non-string datatype.  The reason is I would like to place byte value as tag values to the control, I know I can do this programmatically, but I was trying to confirm if this can be done using declarative statement.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="90,37,0,0" Name="cmbReceiverBytes" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="0xFF DefaultValue" Tag="255" />
    ....
</ComboBox>
```

I am trying all sorts of combination, one of this is placing a parse but it does not work. I would just like to confirm with others if this is possible.

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="0xFF DefaultValue" Tag="{Integer.ParseInt(255)}" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To assign the `Tag` property a byte value you need to use the following XAML syntax:

```
<ComboBoxItem Content="0xFF DefaultValue">
  <ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    <System:Byte>255</System:Byte>
  </ComboBoxItem.Tag>
</ComboBoxItem>
```

You have to add the namespace declaration `xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` to declare the `System` namespace.

Answer (score 6):

You can always use element syntax:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<ComboBoxItem.Tag>
    <sys:Int32>255</sys:Int32/>
</ComboBoxItem.Tag>
```

Also you can create your own [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) which allows you to parse a string to int. Just make it have a constructor that takes an int, then the string will be parsed right away, save it in a field and return it in `ProvideValue`.